# Does error in JS on one URL prevent loading and evaluation of subsequent JS code from other URLs?

Tags: javascript, security, browser

With `<script src="..."></script>` you may load any JS code even from uncontrolled servers. **JSONP** is popular way to work around *same origin* policy and based on evaluation of 3rd party code.

Does this happen if uncontrolled 3rd party code has syntax errors?
or does it happen if uncontrolled 3rd party code has an infinite loop?

May my web application recover from *malfunctions* 3rd party code (syntax error and infinite loop)?.

Will subsequent script loading `<script src="..."></script>` be evaluated after syntax error in 3rd party script?.